# How do I use logical types in Avro IDL?

Tags: avro, idl

I tried the following code in Avro IDL which references the logical type timestamp-millis and it doesn't work.

Is there an import required to use logical types in Avro IDL? Or are logical types not useable, and I need to use the primitive type (long in this case) instead?

```
protocol test {
    record test {
        timestamp-millis time;
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.compiler.idl.ParseException: Undefined name 'timestamp', at line 3, column 9
```

This works of course:

```
protocol test {
    record test {
        long time;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a generic [annotation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/idl.html#minutiae_annotations):

```
protocol test {
    record test {
        @logicalType("timestamp-millis")
        long time;
    }
}
```

There's actually also a shorthand you can use for `timestamp-millis` and a handful of other logical types (the documentation hasn't been released yet, see [here](https://github.com/apache/avro/commit/a92c8f5413e537c116e6b09021b7ed9944467e32) for the full list of aliases):

```
protocol test {
    record test {
        timestamp_ms time;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LogicalType timestamp-millis is used with type **long**, so you may use schema like this:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Test",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "time",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "long",
      "logicalType" : "timestamp-millis"
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is correct, but I was asking about IDL rather than JSON schemas